# Android Toast message not appearing on first request

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mobile-phones, toast

i am having a problem whereby when i open my app from the main screen, whether for the first time or not, when i click one of the buttons to show a toast message, the first time i click the button the toast message doesnt appear but it does appear for the 2nd and every subsequent click. if i then go home and launch my app again i have to wait for the 2 click to see a toast. does anyone know why this may be?

this is how i am using the toast class..

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, msg, duration);
toast.show();
```

Comment: What else is your application doing after initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are properly initializing the variable msg.

Comment: msg comes in as a parameter to the method 'ShowMessage' and always contains text. The event handler for the button click always sends the same text so i dont think it can be a case of not being initialized....

Comment: Try giving it some hard coded value in place of variable msg. If the value comes on the first run then the problem is at msg. Try something like this, 
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "This is a message.", duration);